# compiler failed when building tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_android.sh

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, hexagon-dsp

When I building the nnlib to run it in Hexagon DSP hvx, I follow the command in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/hvx.
It cannot build successfully as the errors occur as following:

```
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc...  arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot ../Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/3.0/tools/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/zhouzhan/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/protobuf':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Comment: Check the `config.log` file. It should contain a more specific error for "C compiler cannot create executables". Then [edit] your question to include the information from `config.log`.